# Flutter - Trying to clear Map<String, TextEditingController>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `ListView.builder` in Flutter that contains multiple `TextField` widgets within cards. These `TextField` widgets are controlled by `TextEditingController` instances stored in a `Map<String, TextEditingController>` called `quantityControllers`. I'm trying to implement a "Clear Quantity" button that not only clears the quantity values but also clears the text within the `TextField` widgets.

Here's how I'm initializing the `quantityControllers`:

```dart
Map<String, TextEditingController> quantityControllers = {};
```

```dart
// Initialize the quantityControllers with default values set to '1'
for (var item in allItemNames) {
  quantityControllers[item] = TextEditingController(text: '1');
}
```

I want to clear it but it's clear only the value it doesn't clear the text field

```dart
Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: showExtraCards
        ? (itemNames.keys.length + extra.keys.length + 1)
        : (itemNames.keys.length + 1),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final category = itemNames.keys.toList()[index];
      final selectedItemName = selectedItemNames[category] ?? '';
      return Card(
        elevation: 4,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              // ... (Row with icon and category name)
              const SizedBox(height: 8),
              SizedBox(
                height: 25,
                child: TypeAheadField<String>(
                  // ... (TypeAheadField configuration)
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 25,
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: quantityControllers[selectedItemName],
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            quantities[selectedItemName] = int.tryParse(value) ?? 0;
                            updateSellingPrice(category);
                          });
                        },
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Quantity',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // ... (Other widgets related to quantity, cost, etc.)
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
),
```

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    // Clear the quantities for all selected items
    for (var itemController in quantityControllers.values) {
      itemController.text = '';
    }
    quantities.forEach((item, value) {
      quantities[item] = 0;
    });

    // Notify the Flutter framework that the state of the widget has changed
    setState(() {});
  },
  child: const Text('Clear Quantity'),
),
```

I'm trying to clear the `TextField` and the value of the qty but its clearing only the value and it doesn't update the UI and clear the `TextField`

| Before Clearing | After Clearing |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Before Clearing] | [image: After Clearing] |

It clears the value but doesn't clear the textfield itself

Comment: Did you try calling "clear()" on itemController insteand of ".text = ''"?

Comment: Where in your code are you initializing the `quantityControllers`? Is it within the `build` method?

Comment: @VincentDR yes i tried

Comment: @MendelG

its inside the class yes

Comment: @MurtadhaAlaali Can you share a full runnable example

Comment: I shared some photos @MendelG